# Android toggle fullscreen in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make my android app toggle between a fullscreen and non-fullscreen mode. Based on other stack overflow answers I've made this extension to do most the work I need...

```
fun AppCompatActivity?.toggleFullscreen(fullscreen: Boolean) {
    if (this == null) return
    val attrs = window.attributes
    if (fullscreen) {
        attrs.flags = attrs.flags or  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
    } else {
        attrs.flags = attrs.flags and WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN.inv()
    }
    window.attributes = attrs
}
```

but this still leaves the naviagtion bar at the bottom of the screen, ive tried adding some other flags (by putting another or after the fullscreen flag) suggested by https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive, incluing:

```
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

but none seemed to work, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

You can call toggle fullscreen using this method

```
fun toggleFullScreen() {
    if (window.decorView.systemUiVisibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    } else {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
    }
}
```

For more details refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive and for details about flags refer this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE